# How to get a pure IPv6 adress? DS Lite emulation

Tags: ipv6

I search a way to emulate a DS Lite Connection. One of my webservices has problems when a user has only a ipv6 adress.

Any suggestions? Payable services would be also ok

My provider has no IPv6 so a tunnel (proxy, vpn) could be a solution

I have also a root server with dualstack ip, but no idea how I must configure my home pc that he use the IPv6 from the linux root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hurricane Electric](https://tunnelbroker.net/) provides free IPv6 over IPv4 tunnels.

Comment: This is an off-topic question. Please do not answer off-topic questions.

Comment: @Xavierjazz Can you explain me, which community would be the right one for this question?